# MSSql (Compact) DELETE-Query with JOIN

Tags: sql, left-join, sql-server-ce, sql-delete

I have this query. I want to delete all entities from AgentsResultLinks-Table, that don't have a link to a entity in Results-Table. I want a solution with one single query.
I got an error caused by '*'.

```
DELETE AgentResultLinks.*
FROM AgentResultLinks LEFT JOIN Results 
ON AgentResultLinks.ResultID = Results.ID
WHERE Results.ID IS NULL
```

Can someone help me to convert this query in a vaid mssql query for compact database ?
The Performance is very important.

Comment: [This link explains the answer why you can't update (or delete maybe) a table that has join on it on SQL Server CE.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6934448/491243)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
DELETE FROM AgentResultLinks 
where ResultID not in(select distinct ID from Results)
```

Comment: this query i had tried before i wrote this post. it's too slow. but it works.

Comment: AgentResultsLinks > 500000 and Results > 20000

Answer (score 9):

Just remove `.*` from `AgentResultLinks.*`

```
DELETE Agent
FROM AgentResultLinks Agent 
LEFT JOIN Results R
       ON Agent.ResultID = R.ID
WHERE R.ID IS NULL;
```

See `DELETE` syntax: [DELETE (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189835.aspx)

[See SQLFiddle Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2e30b/1)

Comment: @Gepro Give alias to table and use it. Updated the answer.

Comment: There was an error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 2,Token line offset = 1,Token in error = FROM ]

Comment: Are you using the same query? Look at [this SQLFiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2e30b/1). I am not getting any error.

Comment: [This link explains the answer why you can't update (or delete maybe) a table that has join on it on SQL Server CE.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6934448/491243)