# Delete rows where date is not minimum

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-delete

I have a table (structure below) that I need to clean up by deleting rows for each `Object_ID`:

```
WHERE Current_Step is NULL and Change = 'change' 
and Date_of_Change <> MIN(Date_of_Change)
```

That is, I need to leave only the row with minimum date for each `Object_ID`.

#### Table sample

| Object_ID | Current_Step | Change | Date_of_Change |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0025307 | NULL | change | 16.11.2021 |
| 0025307 | NULL | change | 19.11.2021 |
| 0025307 | NULL | change | 19.11.2021 |

I am using MS SQL.
There are no primary keys.
All columns are `VARCHAR` except `Date_of_Change` being of type `DATE`.

The reason why I need to clean up this table is because it was incorrectly filled because source query was checking for IF NULL = NULL and then marked those status changes as changed even though they did not change. So I need to revert values back to original date they were changed because if they still have value NULL that means there were no actual changes happening in status.

#### Desired behavior

My attempt in identifying rows that I need to keep:

```
SELECT [Object_ID]
      ,MIN([Date_of_Change])
FROM table
WHERE [Current_Step] IS NULL 
AND [Change] = 'change'
GROUP BY Object_ID
```

I just need to remove other rows with the same Object_ID whose Date_of_Change is not equal to the one identified in query above.

Answer (score 1):

do join on same table like i did on 'Table1223' below.

Example:

```
DELETE tbl 
FROM Table1223 tbl
JOIN (SELECT * FROM Table1223) objID
    ON objID.Object_ID = tbl.Object_ID
WHERE tbl.Date_of_Change > objID.Date_of_Change
```

Answer (score 0):

### Schema

So you have a table with **versioned** objects which holds change records associated to the object with some details and a date.

Now you want to select

- the first change per object
- the oldest (within the *GROUP* of this object's changes)
- using `MIN` function on a `DATE` column-type

This oldest should be retained/kept and stay. All other object change-versions should be deleted.

### Solving

A. Selecting the fist/oldest changes per object in 2 steps.

1. Select the MIN(date) per object:

```
SELECT Object_ID, COUNT(Object_ID) AS Count_Changes, MIN(Date_of_Change) AS First_Change
FROM table
GROUP BY Object_ID
```

Resultset contains each object with the *total* count of changes and the date of the first change.

2. Select the first changes using previous result as [subquery](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Structured_Query_Language/SELECT:_Subquery) in a `JOIN`:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM table t
-- join with a table-subquery having only 2 columns to correlate
JOIN ( 
  SELECT Object_ID, MIN(Date_of_Change) AS First_Change
  FROM table
  WHERE Current_Step is NULL and Change = 'change'
  GROUP BY Object_ID
) m ON t.Object_ID = m.Object_ID AND t.Date_of_Change = m.First_Change
WHERE Current_Step is NULL and Change = 'change'
```

This are the rows to keep and not remove. The first change of each object should be retained and not cleaned.

B. Now we can invert the JOIN-condition to get all the rows, that we want to delete/clean:

1. Change the date-comparison

`) m ON t.Object_ID = m.Object_ID AND t.Date_of_Change = m.First_Change`

to not-equal:

`) m ON t.Object_ID = m.Object_ID AND t.Date_of_Change <> m.First_Change`

2. Run a dry-select first, to get at least the count before deleting.

```sql
SELECT COUNT(Object_ID) AS records_to_remove
FROM table t
-- join with a table-subquery having only 2 columns to correlate
JOIN ( 
  SELECT Object_ID, MIN(Date_of_Change) AS First_Change
  FROM table
  WHERE Current_Step is NULL and Change = 'change'
  GROUP BY Object_ID
) m ON t.Object_ID = m.Object_ID AND t.Date_of_Change <> m.First_Change
WHERE Current_Step is NULL and Change = 'change'
```

3. Prepare the DELETE statement with JOIN (if supported by DBMS):

```
DELETE FROM table t
JOIN ( 
  SELECT Object_ID, MIN(Date_of_Change) AS First_Change
  FROM table
  WHERE Current_Step is NULL and Change = 'change'
  GROUP BY Object_ID
) m ON t.Object_ID = m.Object_ID AND t.Date_of_Change <> m.First_Change
WHERE t.Current_Step is NULL AND t.Change = 'change'
```

---

### Alternative to JOIN try `USING` on other DBMS

Some DBMS do not support JOIN in DELETE statements, but alternatives like [`USING`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11753904/postgresql-delete-with-inner-join):

```sql
DELETE FROM table t
USING ( 
  SELECT Object_ID, MIN(Date_of_Change) AS First_Change
  FROM table t2
  WHERE t2.Current_Step is NULL AND t2.Change = 'change'
) AS m
WHERE ...
AND t.Object_ID = m.Object_ID AND t.Date_of_Change <> m.First_Change
```

Comment: Thank you for the thorough explanation. What is the equivalent of USING for MSSQL?

Comment: Research for `[sql] DELETE with JOIN` using your DBMS-specific tag [tag:sqlserver], [tag:postgresql], etc. - e.g. MS-SQL allows [`JOIN` in DELETE statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12525979/mssql-compact-delete-query-with-join), PostgreSQL has [`USING` as JOIN-alternative for DELETE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11753904/postgresql-delete-with-inner-join).