# UPDATE table1 FROM table2 (using Sql Server Compact)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-ce, sql-server-ce-4

I want to update rows in the `[To]` table, from rows in the `[From]` table, where the keys are equal. So this is what I'd do:

```
UPDATE [To]
SET    [To].[Name]      = [From].[Name],
       [To].[Size]      = [From].[Size],
       [To].[Something] = [From].[Something]
FROM   [From]
WHERE  [To].[Id] = [From].[Id];
go
```

Problem is, [CE doesn't support `FROM` in the `UPDATE` command](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174122%28v=sql.110%29.aspx).

So, how do I change this syntax to work in CE?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to do Sql Server CE table update from another table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1311236/how-to-do-sql-server-ce-table-update-from-another-table)

Comment: @TTeeple No it's not a dupe as that answer doesn't work, and it's the same as Abhishek's answer, which doesn't work.

Comment: How about this one? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6933686/update-on-two-inner-joined-tables-in-sql-server-compact-4?rq=1

Comment: Not used CE, but could you turn it into two statements, a SELECT into variables and use those in the UPDATE?

Comment: @MattAllwood Maybe I don't know. I'm hoping I can do it in one step, as I need to do this in an EF migrations `Sql()` call. Two steps would be to introduce another problem.

Comment: @hbob I know, ugly as sin, but not allowing FROM is a major obstacle for anything else. It sounds as though it can cope with multiple SQL statements in one call, so the other requirements are quite low. Hope you don't need to do this too often though :-/

Comment: @hbob it's also the suggested solution to this similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6933686/update-on-two-inner-joined-tables-in-sql-server-compact-4?lq=1

Answer (score 1):

Try the below snippet (not tested) -

```
UPDATE [To]
SET    [To].[Name]      = [From].[Name],
       [To].[Size]      = [From].[Size],
       [To].[Something] = [From].[Something]
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM [FROM] WHERE [To].[Id] = [From].[Id])
```

Comment: Nope it says `The column name is not valid. [ Node name (if any) = From,Column name = Name ]`

Comment: It seems that this can't be done in a single query when `UPDATE` needs to be done for **[TO]** from **[FROM]**. As per the suggestions the value needs to be stored in some variable and then use the variable to do the update.

Comment: how would you do that?

Comment: @hbob - the limitations of CE is forcing to make the update in two steps, either you choose to store the values matched between two tables and then do a simple update or to do a delete first based on the join conditions and then do a fresh insert. Problem is I don't have any CE system handy where I can test and let you know so all my solutions might seem vague.

Answer (score -1):

Update to
Set to.fld1 = from1.fld1
from table1 to inner join table from1
on to.id = from1.id