# MSSQLCE: Subquery returns parsing error

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-ce, sql-server-ce-4

I've added an ID column (**personID**) into a table (**personList**) instead of another field: **personPin**

Now I need to fill empty foreign key field (**seenPersonID**) of another table (**personAttendances**)

```
UPDATE personAttendances
SET seenPersonID =
(SELECT personID FROM personList WHERE (personAttendances.personPin = personPin))
```

Why does SQL engine say there is an error parsing the query? Or how can I fill the field on other table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need something like

```
UPDATE personAttendances 
SET seenPersonID = b.personID
FROM personAttendances a
INNER JOIN personList b ON (b.personPin = a.personPin)
```

Comment: Optional FROM clause not allowed in this query type.

Comment: @Nime Cloud: sorry, I didn't realize that you have `sql-server-ce`, not `sql-server`. I don't think you can do it with CE. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1311236/how-to-do-sql-server-ce-table-update-from-another-table

Comment: I've exported to SQL Server 2008.

Comment: Does it show an error on SQLServer 2008? It seems perfectly valid to me and I tested it on 2008...

Comment: No problem with 2008. Thanks. However 2008 doesn't support Compact 4.0 here and importing from 2008 to SQLCE was a headache.